# Calculated Column Modification

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I've got the following file name convention for images in an SP document library -

**CQYr  UnqID   Qual      Name**

2020 RR0000 Bus Driver Roger Rabbit

I am using the following in a calculate column in that same library to extract the year out of the file name.

=LEFT(Title,(FIND(" ",Title)-1))

I have columns for the other three. How would I modify the calculation for each so that only the UnqID appears in that column, Qual in that column, and Name in that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular example, you can try the following formulas:

```
1) CQYr 
=LEFT(Title,4)

2) UnqID
=MID(Title,5,6)

3) Qual
=MID(Title,13,FIND(" ",Title,17)-13)

4) Name
=MID(Title,LEN(LEFT(Title,FIND(" ",Title,17))&" "),20)
```

[image]

Note: Need to validate for other values of [Title], specifically value of **Qual** in [Title]. If we know the MIN and MAX LEN(Qual) in the entire set of [Title] values, the formulas can be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, it is very helpful. Does the fact that each Title is a different length, beyond the first 10 characters?

Comment: For 'Title' the condition is returning 'Firefighter I John Z' or 'Firefighter II Paul'; and for Name its returning 'II Paul Cra' and 'Operator, Pumper Eri'. At the Qual and Name points the numbers are off, but also what is being counted is off. The only sure thing are the 'space' in between each. Thoughts? Is this correctable? Thanks!

Comment: The Quals go from as short as 'Medical' to as long as 'Self-Contained Breathing Apparatus Fit Test. Likewise, an entire 'Title can go from as few as 20 characters to almost 100, depending on the length of the Members name and the Qual being referenced.

Comment: The problem we're running into to extract [Qual] from [Title] is: no definite number of [space] chars. You have zero to 4 space chars within [Qual]. MID() function can target to extract from a particular [space] char, however, it needs to know the location where to start from. For your data, that start position varies, and that's quite challenging.

Comment: Yes; it is as I assumed. Thank you. What has been provided with the CQYear and UniqueID calculations is enough, for now, too allow for sufficient filtering of existing documents. All new uploads will have Qual and Name added automatically through a flow.

Comment: Wait! Come back! Can I, create a calculated column that uses the UnqID data that we've successfully extracted from the Title, to pull the 'FullName', 'First', 'Last', or any other data from a List that also has the exact same UnqID? If Joe Blow's UnqID is in the calculated column of the Library, can that data be referenced in a Library calculated column that is using the UnqID data to compare it to the UnqID column in a List, and where they are the same return content of the 'FullName' column in that List?

Comment: In calculated column, you can't reference other List or Library to look up and extract matched values on a certain columns, in this case matching UnqID and get FullName. However, using Flow, you can match values in [UnqID], already a calculated column in the current library, with another List and then extract 'FullName' and update the current library. That's doable. I think, you first finish the tasks that your're doing and I will help on this as well

Comment: All done. Flow worked great. All file names have been updated. Now, where were we?